# Joining tables by more than one field in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, sql-server

I am joining multiple tables together with different aspects of chemical analysis result data. Some of the joins need to match up with more than just the field they are being joined on. (I am accessing all of this data from a SQL Server Database) I have a table containing a column called 'Result_Unit' and a joined column called 'Sample State' and I am joining another table to this with the join field being 'Sample State'. This second table also has a column called 'Result_Unit' which needs to match up. The Result_Unit column needs to match between the two because there are multiple result units that determine which sample state corresponds to each sample. I have an example of the SQL Query that seems to solve the problem but using a modification of the query in the 'Make Query Table' tool does not seem to work and I can't figure out how to make it work with ArcPy. The line of the SQL Query goes:

```
join STD_UNITS SUR on SUR.sample_state=FM.sample_state AND SUR.result_unit = C.result_unit
```

Where C is my initial table containing sample results and FM is the table joined to my initial table C which contains the column 'sample state'.

If I do regular Add Join with all of the tables I have I come out with mismatched rows because I don't have the second matching columns (Result Unit) match up with the joins.

I would like to know how I can join the STD_UNITS table with these others while indicating that the shared 'result unit' columns should match.

Is there a way I can do something similar to what the SQL 'AND' is doing in ArcGIS Pro 2.8 or do I need to do this in SQL?

Comment: Join field between 2 tables first and join again to fearure class.